# How can I find the device file in `/dev` via bus number and device number listed by `lsusb`?

Tags: linux, usb, device

When I attach removable USB hard disk to my computer, I can distinguish it from others via the name of manufacture and device name. However, I can't exactly know what is the device file in /dev (e.g. sda, sdb, sdc...) corresponding to this USB storage device.

Is there a way to find out the device file according to the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/361885/how-do-i-figure-out-which-dev-is-a-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 0):

I always do like this: 
If this USB device is the last one to remove/insert, you can get it from 'dmesg'. you can easy to see sdxxx in dmesg print out. that's what your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can know exactly the `/dev/path/to/your/device` using `lsusb`.

Sample output:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

According to the previous example, you can locate the `char` device that corresponds to the Logitech USB receiver ( for wireless mouse and keyboard ) by examining the two numbers before the colon ( : ).

It would be `/dev/bus/002/008`
Notice the last two numbers ( last directory then the `char` device file itself ).
They are the same as the first two numbers in the line that says `Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver`.

So the path is always `/dev/bus/`*[first number]*`/`*[second number]*.